# Delphi sharesheet xe5

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, delphi-xe5

How to share multiple images simultaneously with sharesheet xe5 with delphi for android?

In the official video it shows only one image.

http://youtu.be/JS6o4RgDX1g

Comment: Please provide some detail of what you have done or how you are trying to do this

Comment: I want to take multiple photos, store Timages, mark the best with checkbox and send to email, facebook, etc. google +

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

The TShowShareSheet has only a Bitmap property, for a single image.

You can, however, call the dialog multiple times, although it may compromise user experience.